# JPA: Nested transactional method is not rolled back

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jta

**UPD 1:** Upon further research I think the following information may be useful:

- I obtain datasource through JNDI lookup on WildFly 9.0.2, then 'wrap' it into in instance of `HikariDataSource` (e. g. `return new HikariDataSource(jndiDSLookup(dsName))`).
- the transaction manager that ends up being used is `JTATransactionManager`.
- I do not configure the transaction manager in any way.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I am experiencing an issue with JPA/Hibernate and (maybe) Spring-Boot where DB changes introduced in a transactional method of one class called from a  transactional method of another class are committed even though the changes in the caller method are rolled back (as they should be).

Here are my transactional services

`StuffService`:

```
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = IOException.class)
public class StuffService {

    @Inject private BarService barService;
    @Inject private StuffRepository stuffRepository;

    public Stuff updateStuff(Stuff stuff) {

        try {
            if (null != barService.doBar(stuff)) {
                stuff.setSomething(SOMETHING);
                stuff.setSomethingElse(SOMETHING_ELSE);
                return stuffRepository.save(stuff);
            }
        } catch (FirstCustomException e) {
            logger.error("Blah", e);
            throw new SecondCustomException(e.getMessage());
        }

        throw new SecondCustomException("Blah 2");
    }

    // other methods
}
```

and `BarService`:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BarService {

    @Inject private EntityARepository entityARepository;
    @Inject private EntityBRepository entityBRepository;

    /* 
     * updates existing entity A and persists new entity B. 
     */
    public EntityA doBar(Stuff stuff) throws FirstCustomException {

        EntityA a = entityARepository.findOne(/* some criteria */);
        a.setSomething(SOMETHING);

        EntityB b = new EntityB();
        b.setSomething(SOMETHING);
        b.setSomethingElse(SOMETHING_ELSE);

        entityBRepository.save(b);
        return entityARepository.save(a);
    }

// other methods
}
```

`EntityARepository` and `EntityBRepository` are very similar Spring-Boot repositories defined like this:

```
public interface EntityARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, Long>{

    EntityA findOne(/* some criteria */);
}
```

`FirstCustomException` extends `Throwable`

`SecondCustomException` extends `RuntimeException`

`Stuff` entity is versioned, and every once in a while it is concurrently updated by `StuffService.updateStuff()`. In that case changes to one of the  `stuff` instances are rolled back, as expected, but everything that happens in the `barService.doBar()` ends up being committed.

This puzzles me quite a lot since transaction propagation on both methods should be `REQUIRED` (the default one) and both methods belong to different classes, hence `@Transactional` should apply for both.

I did see [Transaction is not completely rolled back after server throws OptimisticLockException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491029/transaction-is-not-completely-rolled-back-after-server-throws-optimisticlockexce)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491029/transaction-is-not-completely-rolled-back-after-server-throws-optimisticlockexce)

But it did not really answer my question.

Can anyone please give me an idea of what's going on?

Thank you.

Comment: What error/exception causes the rollback in one of the service?

Comment: @Mubin: `OptimisticLockException`, which is caused, quite predictably, by `StaleObjectStateException`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a 'nested' transaction - these services are operating in completely independent transactions.  If you want the rollback of one to affect the other, you need to have them take part in the same transaction rather than start its own.

Or if your issue is that there is a problem with the version of 'stuff' passed into the doBar method and you want it verified, you will need to do something with the stuff instance that would cause an optimistic lock check, and so result in an exception if it is stale.  see [EntityManager.lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#lock(java.lang.Object,%20javax.persistence.LockModeType))

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for the answer. I thought that with the `REQUIRED` propagation level `barService.doBar()` would join the transaction started by `Stuff Service.updateStuff()`. Why do you think they are associated with separate transactions?

Comment: yes, required means it is required to be wrapped in a transaction. Is your calling method in control of that transaction, or is it non-transactional leaving the container to start/commit a transaction for each of these separate calls?

Comment: it is one transactional method calling another transactional method. My understanding is that they both should roll back, since the called method is supposed to join the same transaction started by the caller method. But that is not the case right now, if there is an exception in the caller method, only that one is rolled back.

Comment: They should if configured correctly.  You will have to show your configuration to make sure all your resources are able to participate in the global transaction, and that the transaction controllers involved are able to mark it for rollback on error.

Comment: Sure, what else is involved in transactions configuration other than annotated service classes?